# Debian/Raspbian - Send Email "back in time"

Tags: email, debian, raspberry-pi, time, raspbian

For the sake of entertainment i am looking for a way so send an email "back in time". With that i mean sending & receiving an email with a timestamp from the past. For that purpose i am running 2 Postfix&Dovecot-Email-Servers on Raspbian & Debian. Those are the two i want to use for my magical trick, by sending the mail to each other. I tried changing the time on the server A, so that it sends the mail with a timestamp from the past. Of course i get a connection timeout (makes sense why) when trying to send it. Any other ideas? Or how can i fix the problem?

Comment: Side note: it magically worked again. But the time, which is displayed by the receiving client, matches the sender's client time. How can i change that time without modifying the client's device's time? Clients and devices tested: Ubuntu with Thunderbird, Android with standart-samsung-email-client

Comment: It's on and off. sometimes i can connect to it when the date is set back, sometimes i can't.